# Se puede cambiar el orden por defecto de un botón de radio?

Tags: jquery

Cómo harían para cambiar el orden por defecto de estas opciones? Siempre aparece seleccionado el de arriba, como sería un `script` para que solo lo cambie a la opción de abajo?

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Archive</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="radio-custom">
<input type="radio" name="archive" id="radio-archive" value="true" checked="">
<label for="radio-archive">OPCIÓN 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-custom">
<input type="radio" name="OPCIÓN 2" value="false">
<label for="radio-no-archive">Upload each file separately</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Este `script` lo pondría en el Tampermonkey

Comment: el primer radio tiene el atributo checked explícito, no es por defult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si el tampermonkey es como el greasemonkey la sintaxis jquery sería:

```
jQuery('#radio-no-archive').prop("checked", true);
```

peero, con el html que proporcionas no funcionaría pues el name del primer checkbox no coincide con el segundo y el segundo aunque tiene un `label for` carece de `id`.

Adjunto html arreglado, si no es el original fijate que ondas el segundo ejemplo.

```js
jQuery('#radio-no-archive').prop("checked", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Archive</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="radio-custom">
      <input type="radio" name="archive" id="radio-archive" value="true" checked="">
      <label for="radio-archive">OPCIÓN 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-custom">
      <input type="radio" name="archive" value="false" id="radio-no-archive">
      <label for="radio-no-archive">Upload each file separately</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Para el html dado podemos intentar algo así:

```js
// uncheck el primero
jQuery('input[name="archive"]').prop('checked', false);
// check el segundo
jQuery('input[name="OPCIÓN 2"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Archive</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="radio-custom">
      <input type="radio" name="archive" id="radio-archive" value="true" checked="">
      <label for="radio-archive">OPCIÓN 1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-custom">
      <input type="radio" name="OPCIÓN 2" value="false">
      <label for="radio-no-archive">Upload each file separately</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Por si se busca algo genérico (varias opciones, la primera checked, seleccionar la última):

```js
jQuery('input[name="archive"]').last().prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Archive</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="radio-custom">
      <input type="radio" name="archive" id="radio-archive" value="true" checked="">
      <label for="radio-archive">Upload an archive (subir todo junto en un archivo comprimido)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-custom">
      <input type="radio" name="archive" value="idk" id="radio-no-idea">
      <label for="radio-no-idea">Halp can't decide (Ni idea que hacer)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-custom">
      <input type="radio" name="archive" value="false" id="radio-no-archive">
      <label for="radio-no-archive">Upload each file separately (subir cada archivo por separado)</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bueno jaja me solucionaste hasta el error mio de editar el `HTML`. quise editar el `</label>` pero fallé al editar el segundo, cosa que no me di cuenta hasta que ustedes lo advirtieron, muy agradecido por la respuesta y el `código` me funciona perfecto, saludos!

Answer (score 2):

Para que aparezca seleccionado el de abajo, sólo tienes que ponerle el atributo `checked`:

> El atributo `checked` es un atributo booleano que proporciona la
>   comprobación predeterminada del elemento de entrada. Cuando se agrega
>   el atributo `checked`, si el control no tiene una [comprobación
>   sucia](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#concept-input-checked-dirty), el agente de usuario debe establecer la comprobación del
>   elemento en verdadero; cuando se elimina el atributo `checked`, si el
>   control no tiene una comprobación sucia, el agente de usuario debe
>   establecer la comprobación del elemento en falso.
>
> -<sub>[El atributo `checked` en la especificación HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-checked)</sub>

Por ejemplo:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Archive</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="radio-custom">
<input type="radio" name="archive" id="radio-archive" value="true" />
<label for="radio-archive">OPCIÓN 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-custom">
<input type="radio" name="OPCIÓN 2" value="false" checked />
<label for="radio-no-archive">Upload each file separately</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

En cuanto al primero, conviene quitarle esto: <s>`checked=""`</s>

---

> #### MUY IMPORTANTE

Si tus dos radio están relacionados y quieres presentar el último seleccionado por defecto, hay un problema: cuando se selecciona el primero, el último no se desmarca, se quedan ambos seleccionados (código de más arriba). Esto en teoría sería contrario a la naturaleza de los radio button. Para evitar ese comportamiento, basta con que le des el mismo `name` a los dos. Haciéndolo así, cuando uno se seleccione, el otro se desmarca automáticamente.

Si por algún motivo tienen que tener nombres diferentes (lo cual sería poco probable y/o difícilmente justificable), entonces puedes implementar código Javascript para devolver a los elementos su comportamiento normal.

Por ejemplo:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Archive</label>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="radio-custom">
<input type="radio" name="archive" id="radio-archive" value="true" />
<label for="radio-archive">OPCIÓN 1</label>
</div>
<div class="radio-custom">
<input type="radio" name="archive" value="false" checked />
<label for="radio-no-archive">Upload each file separately</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias amigo, es de mucha ayuda la info q pones y explicación. en efecto puse mal el `HTML` y expertos como ustedes se dieron cuenta de mi error, ambos `name=` originalmente son idénticos, fue error mio intentar editar el `</label>` pero le edité por error el segundo `name=`. gracias de nuevo y saludos